# Hibernate select all query executes extremely slowly

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have some simple code that is supposed to select all teacher objects from a table of teachers in my mysql database. When I run similar queries for other domain objects, it is extremely fast, but for some reason this query takes forever. Also if I run a select all query from mysql workbench it executes instantly, so I think the problem is with my hibernate mapping. There are only 30 ish entries in the table so there is no reason this should be taking long.

Hibernate mapping xml file:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="org.myschool.domain.Teacher" table="teacher">
    <id name="teacher_id" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="teacher_id" />
        <generator class="increment" />
    </id>
    <property name="firstName" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="first_name" length="20" not-null="true"/>
    </property>
    <property name="lastName" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="last_name" length="30" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="middleInitial" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="middle_initial" length="1" not-null = "false"/>
    </property>

    <set name="wantsCourses" table="teacher_want" inverse="false" lazy="true" fetch="select" cascade="all">
        <key>
            <column name="teacher_id" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <many-to-many entity-name="org.myschool.domain.Course">
            <column name="course_id" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-many>
    </set>

    <set name="eligibleCourses" table="teacher_eligible" inverse="false" lazy="true" fetch="select" cascade="all">
        <key>
            <column name="teacher_id" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <many-to-many entity-name="org.myschool.domain.Course">
            <column name="course_id" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-many>
    </set>

    <set name="teacherTranscript" table="assigned_course"  inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="teacher_id" not-null="true" />
        </key>

        <one-to-many class="org.myschool.domain.AssignedCourse" />
    </set>

</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

This is the method being called that takes so long :

```
public List<Teacher> findAll() {
    try {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Teacher> results = (List<Teacher>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createCriteria("org.myschool.domain.Teacher").list();
        log.debug("find all successful, result size: " + results.size());
        return results;
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        log.error("find all failed", re);
        throw re;
    }
}
```

And this is the actual hibernate query being executed:

```
Hibernate: select this_.teacher_id as teacher_1_8_0_, this_.first_name as first_na2_8_0_, this_.last_name as last_nam3_8_0_, this_.middle_initial as middle_i4_8_0_ from teacher this_
```

Here's the sql command that makes the teacher table:

```
CREATE TABLE teacher(
            teacher_id INT(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
            first_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
            middle_initial CHAR(1),
            last_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: How do you know the query is where the bottleneck is?

Comment: try native queries in hibernate and then check is it faster. To write native query check this link (https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html). If performance is faster in native query, then you can think of fine tuning wrt hibernate part.

Comment: @JimGarrison i have show sql enabled and thats the last line it always prints before it gets really slow. does that in multiple parts of the program.

Comment: @Rakesh i tried using a native query, it again took extremely long for the teacher entity but not for any other entities. I think it has to be something with my mapping but im not sure what